# iOS Project Structure for Presentation App

Tags: objective-c, ios, structure, presentation, application-structure

- I'm gonna build presentation app, which will present a brand
  product.
- Presentation will have multiple slides (states) with common
  background.
- In some slides I can go back to previous slide

My questions: 
1. Do I have to use View Based Application? 
2. For each state (slide) should I use separate `UIViewControllers`?
3. **What best structure for presentation app you would suggest?**
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS5 SDK introduces **Storyboard**. You should definitely look into this for your presentation app, here is a tutorial on [Using Storyboard](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html).

Comment: That link seems to be broken... I have no restriction on my laptop and browser itself.

Comment: That link works fine on my end .. http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html

Comment: Ok I got it with proxy. Country problem i think )

Comment: Thx, it opened my eyes for something new I didn't know before this morning)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do I have to use View Based Application?
> 2. For each state (slide) should I use separate UIViewControllers?
> 3. What best structure for presentation app you would suggest?

1. No. The difference between the various app project templates lies mainly in how the view controllers are set up. You can read all the provided code and modify it however you like for your project. If you don't plan to use a navigation controller or a tab bar controller in your app, the view-based app template might be the easiest one to go with, but choose whichever template best suits your needs and don't be shy about changing the code.
2. Not necessarily. If all the slides are treated the same way, it might make sense to create a single SlideViewController class that can display any slide and knows how to transition to the next or previous slide, which it might do by using animation to move one slide off the screen and the next into position.
3. I don't think anyone could say what's "best" without a lot more information about your requirements, but personally I'd lean toward either a single view controller instance for all the slides, or a single slide view controller class with one instance per slide. I'd want to treat all slides uniformly -- you don't want to have to figure out which view controller class to use with any given slide.